# Trying to edit a comment after the grace period: The message "This comment was edited 1 time" is misleading

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, edits, grace-period

I tried to edit my comment which I had edited already in Pro Webmasters but I'm not allowed to edit and when I moved my mouse courser to edit symbol it indicating a message that "This comment was edited 1 time". Why do the SE system not allowing to edit more than 1 time? How we can edit a comment more than 1 time if I missed any thing in our comment?

**Edit:** I got the answer from Anna Lear that our system won't allow user to edit his comment after 5 minutes. So my feature request is our SE system should inform our users that why he/she can't edit his comment since it's not informing the reason for not allowing the user to edit.Also the user should know the reason so that they won't try to edit their comment after 5 minutes and they will be in alert while writing comments. Instead of showing "**This comment was edited 1 time**" We should display a message like **"You can't edit your comment after 5 minutes"**.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of edits is unlimited, but you can only edit comments within 5 minutes of posting them. Judging by the screenshot, the comment was posted 9 minutes ago, so you missed that window.

Comment: Ok fine. Then why did the message was showing "This comment was edited 1 time"? Is this a warning or just an information?

Comment: It's just information.

Comment: If our SE system won't allow us to edit comments which we posted 5 mints before then how do a new user know, why he is not allowed to edit his comment?

Comment: If the system locked that comment and that user trying to edit it means SE should tell "You can't edit your comment after 5 minutes". right?

Comment: Or am i missing any thing?

Comment: Probably couldn't hurt, but there aren't that many people confused by it that we'd want to complicate the UI here. Feel free to post a feature request, if you like.

Comment: How can I post a feature request? I would like to request this.

Comment: I have edit the question by adding feature request tag.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar That works. You should also edit your question here to add some details about how you want this warning/error to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I have edited my question. Since i'm not very fluent in English, please edit it If I have made any thing wrong or missed any thing.

Comment: What's the reason we can't edit our comments after 5 minutes? 5 minutes is so small. Perhaps we find out a missing sentence for example, 15 minutes after posting the comment. But generally, I'm against any restrictions on editing comments because of time. It is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

That little drawing of a pencil is not what you click on to edit a comment. It's just an icon that is displayed to show everybody that the comment has been edited.

To edit a comment, you have to click on the "edit" text, which disappears after five minutes.